# Is it correct to say "technology has been introduced and improved in medical science education?

Tags: phrase-usage

The tense after and is present perfect but do you think it needs "has" again? Or one "has" before and is enough?

Comment: What idea are you trying to express? That technology was introduced in medical science education, and it has improved quite a lot since its introduction?  Or that its use in medical science education is what has led to the improvements?  "has been introduced and improved" is awkward and vague.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I meant the second idea you wrote.

Comment: The medical science education has improved the technology? Coz that's what you've got now...

Answer (score 0):

Using "has" once before "been introduced" is sufficient. It serves as the auxiliary verb for both "introduced" and "improved".

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to have **has** act as the auxiliary for two verbs (though it is grammatical). Instead, convert the verb **introduce** to the noun **introduction** and make it the subject of your sentence:

> The introduction of technology in medical education has led to improvements in the technology itself.